# Perl Switch statement: Trouble using OR (logical operators in general) in given/when conditions

Tags: perl, switch-statement, logical-operators

Basically I want to get user input and decide what to do, and I need to have the same outcome even for different user inputs sometimes. Example code:

```
given ($command) {
      when ('a' || 'add') {add}
      when ('s' || 'subtract') {subtract}
      when ('m' || 'multiply') {multiply}
      when ('d' || 'divide') {divide}
      default { print "try again, usage: add, subtract, multiply, divide (a, s, m, d)\n" }
```

Now the trouble with this is that it only works if I type the single letter commands at the beginning of the or statements. If I type something like "add" into the prompt, I get the default message telling me to try again.

I could make separate cases for these, but it would just have the same body as the single letters, which is just redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `given`/`when` construct uses the smart match operator, which doesn't have any special-case behavior for the `||` operator. The expression

```
'a' || 'add'
```

evaluates to `'a'`, so it just matches `$command` against the string `'a'`.

If you want to match `$command` against any of a list of values, you can use an array value:

```
given ($command) {
    when ([qw(a add)]) { add }
...
```

(As usual, there are several ways to express this.)

References:

`perldoc -f given`

[`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html); search for "Switch statements" and "Smart matching in detail".

**EDIT :**

Another approach for this problem, if you want to allow `$command` to be any prefix of the command name (e.g., `"s"`, `"su"`, `"sub"`, ..., `"subtract"`) is something like this:

```
sub match {
    my($s, $target) = @_;
    return index($target, $s) == 0;
}

...

if (match($command, 'add') { ... }
elsif (match ($command, 'subtract') { ... }
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, you're right, I did not realize that was an array :)

Comment: there is a special case (for `when`, not smartmatch) documented, but AFAICT it doesn't seem to work. it's case 10 in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when

Answer (score 2):

You are simply using the wrong synthax, try in this way :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use warnings;

print 'Enter your command : ';
chomp( my $command = <> );

given ($command) {
      say 'Adding something' when ['a', 'add'];
      say 'Subtracting something' when ['s', 'subtract'];
      say 'Multiplying something' when ['m', 'multiply'];
      say 'Dividing something' when ['d', 'divide'];
      default { say "try again, usage: add, subtract, multiply, divide (a, s, m, d)\n" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"when" evaluate a regexp.

You cannot use || but you can use a regular expression :)

```
given ($command) {
    when (/(^a$|^add$)/) {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```